# Matlab : Conversion of Triangular mesh to Regular (Square) Mesh

Tags: matlab

mI currently possess a triangular mesh model of a heart that is loaded into Matlab for further manipulation. The current problem is the that I require a regular (square) mesh model of the heart in order to perform proper texture mapping of an image.  Can anyone provide a function or even another program that can convert the current TRIANGULAR mesh model to a regular SQUARE model? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with the FEX submission [GridTriMesh](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14646-gridtrimesh).